# npm package not executed on linux

Tags: linux, node.js, executable, npm

Today I tried to publish an own npm [package](https://npmjs.org/package/symlinker). When installing it via

```
    npm install symlinker -g
```

it should be executable as

```
    symlinker (args)
```

This will work using Windows but I couldn't execute it via Linux (Raspberry Pi). Using linux it 
will output the following error (command: symlinker):

```
    : No such file or directory
```

My first guess was that it might be a problem with the nodejs executable which is be default "node" (Windows) and "nodejs" (Linux). Somehow I managed to install nodejs as "node" on my Raspberry Pi so that this can't be the problem. As this is my first try to publish a npm package I think that it's most likely an package.json fault.

[github repository](https://github.com/FlorianWendelborn/Symlinker)

Any idea what could cause the problem? Is it the fault of my Raspberry Pi or the configuration of it or is it caused by my npm package?

Comment: @user568109 I forgot to mention that I tried that too. Unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: @user568109 Please do not recommend sudo where it does not make sense. There's no error about privileges/access rights. Do not spread the 'sudo everything' / 'chmod 777 everything' ideas to make things work. This is bad for everyone.

Comment: The file having an executable bit is important for this to work and that is the exact problem the OP is facing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably caused due to two reasons,

#### 1. The executable nodejs binary doesn't have proper executable permissions.

#### 2. There is no proper CRLF after your `#!/usr/bin/env node` at the top of the binary file that you are trying to execute.

Both of the above problems occur, when you try to publish a package from windows and install it using npm from a linux machine.

Try solving the problems 1 and 2 manually. Or try publishing from a linux machine and try it again.

Hope that helps.

Comment: It really was the CRLF, thanks for helping me out with this. I would have never thought about that.